# Slide out single div at a time

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/SDCH/qqq58vsr/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showblockone">
<div id="slideout">
    <label id="slideout_tab2" for="showblockone" title="Track your Order">
        <i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <div id="slideout_inner" style="top: 51px;
">
<span>Track your Order</span>
    </div>
</div>
<br><input type="checkbox" id="showblocktwo">
<div id="slideout" class="blockTwo">
    <label id="slideout_tab3" for="showblocktwo" title="Refer to Friend">
        <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x" style="margin-left: -7px;"></i>
    </label>
    <div id="slideout_inner" style="    top: 102px;height: 54px;">
<span>Refer to Friend</span>
    </div>
</div>
<br><input type="checkbox" id="showblockthree">
<div id="slideout">
    <label id="slideout_tab4" for="showblockthree" title="Refer to Friend">
        <i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" style="margin-left: -7px;"></i>
    </label>
    <div id="slideout_inner" style="top: 160px; height: 54px;">
<span>Easy Return</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to make only one div slideout at a time and slide in other div if any other div is slided out for demo please have a look at jsfiddle link

Comment: Please rephrase what you are looking to achieve. I can't seem to understand your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `input type="radio"` with same `name` attribute.

I make some changes in it. I hope it will help you.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/qqq58vsr/2/)